# Replace multiple chars in string (Make valid folder name)

Tags: c#, string, replace, char

Given a string and an array of chars:

```
string userDir = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
char[] chars Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
```

If want to replace all chars in "chars" in the "userDir" string to make an valid directory name out of the username. Or can I assume that every username is a valid directory?

The best idea I have yet is nesting two loops ... but I'm looking for a shorter solution.

Or is there an other method to generate a valid directory name?

Comment: What kind of folder are you basing on the user's name? If you need their user folder, or a folder under that, then use `Environment.GetFolderPath()` along with the `Environment.SpecialFolders` enum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your code:

```
string userDir = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
char[] chars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
```

You could always do:

```
Array.ForEach(chars, c => userDir = userDir.Replace(c, '_'));
```

To replace any invalid char with an underscore (or whatever neutral character you'd like...).

**UPDATE**: As Steve Fallows indicated, the `\` and `:` are valid path chars but not valid folder name chars.  Instead, we should use the `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` method:

```
char[] chars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
```

And then continue as before.

Comment: Two caveats: GetInvalidPathChars() does not include ':' and '\' which are valid *path* characters but not valid in one folder level name. Also the Array.ForEach must assign back to the userDir var to actually change the string. See my answer for a slightly more robust version.

Answer (score 1):

```
// This only needs to be initialized once.
var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Select(c => Regex.Escape(c.ToString()));
Regex regex = new Regex(string.Join("|", invalidChars));

// Replace all invalid characters with "_".
userDir = regex.Replace(userDir, "_");
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on James Michael Hare's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9708712/18882), here is a slightly more robust version to correct a string that is to be used as a single folder level in a path:

```
private string ReplaceInvalidFolderNameChars(string proposedFolderName_)
{
    char[] chars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
    Array.Resize(ref chars, chars.Length + 2);
    chars[chars.Length - 2] = ':';
    chars[chars.Length - 1] = '\\';
    Array.ForEach(chars, c => proposedFolderName_ = proposedFolderName_.Replace(c, '_'));
    return proposedFolderName_;
}
```

**UPDATE**: Simplified version based on James' update:

```
private string ReplaceInvalidFolderNameChars(string proposedFolderName_)
{
    char[] chars = Path.GetInvalidFilenameChars();
    Array.ForEach(chars, c => proposedFolderName_ = proposedFolderName_.Replace(c, '_'));
    return proposedFolderName_;
}
```